# pdfTeX warning: destination with same identifier has been already used, duplicate ignored (weird behavior)

Tags: hyperref, environments, counters, amsart, amsthm

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{myexercise}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{ }{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\newtheoremstyle{mypart}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ -- #3}}

\theoremstyle{myexercise}
\newtheorem{Exo}{Exercise}
\theoremstyle{mypart}
\newtheorem{Part}{Part}[Exo]
\renewcommand*\thePart{\Roman{Part}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exo}[A cool exercise]
\begin{Part}
\label{p:ex1:I}
Prove that $1=0$.
\end{Part}
\begin{Part}
Deduce from Part~\ref{p:ex1:I} that this exercise is wrong.
\end{Part}
\end{Exo}

\begin{Exo}
\begin{Part}
Let $a=b$. Deduce that $0=0$.
\end{Part}
\begin{Part}
Let $a=42$. For what values of $b$ do we have $a=b$?
\end{Part}
\end{Exo}
\end{document}
```

The warning I get is the following:

> pdf TeX warning (ext4): destination
>   with the same identifier
>   (name{Part.1.1}) has b een already
>   used, duplicate ignored
>
> \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box
>   \AtBeginShipoutBox 
>                                                     \fi \fi  l.35 \end{document}
>                      pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same
>   identifier  (name{Part.2.1}) has been
>   already used, duplicate ignored
>
> \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box
>   \AtBeginShipoutBox 
>                                                     \fi \fi  l.35 \end{document}
>                      ] (./TestHyperref.aux) )

This looks like a strange behavior to me. Or have I done anything wrong?

Besides, the error completely disappears if I use, e.g., enumerates inside the Part environment, as in

```
...
\begin{Part}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Prove that $1=0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{Part}
...
```

Also, there's no error if I remove the hyperref package. Unfortunately, I need to use hyperref.

Any idea?

Comment: Note that this is not an error, only a warning. Actually, as long as you have only one reference to a part, there won't be a problem. Only if you have a reference to e.g. Part I in Exercise 1 and Part I in Exercise 2, the hyperlinks that hyperref creates will point to the same target.

Comment: @Michael Indeed, and the weirdest is that the warnings disappear altogether when I put an enumerate environment inside the Part (which is what I almost always do, since there are usually numbered questions in Parts).

Answer (score 12):

try

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Thank you! small change, big result

Comment: This works to solve an issue with renaming equations while using hyperref as well. This is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to use nested theorems with `article.cls` and `ntheorem`, now the problem seems to come from a conflict between `amsart` and `hyperref`. `ntheorem` has an option to avoid compatibility with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}  

\newtheorem{Exo}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{Part}{Part}[Exo]
\renewcommand*\thePart{\Roman{Part}} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{Exo}[A cool exercise]
\begin{Part}
\label{p:ex1:I}
Prove that $1=0$.
\end{Part}
\begin{Part}
Deduce from Part~\ref{p:ex1:I} that this exercise is wrong.
\end{Part}
\end{Exo}

\begin{Exo}
\begin{Part}
Let $a=b$. Deduce that $0=0$.
\end{Part}
\begin{Part}
Let $a=42$. For what values of $b$ do we have $a=b$?
\end{Part}
\end{Exo} 
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be between `amsart`and `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually using (a modification of) the amsbook class. I don't quite understand why nesting several theorem environments should be a problem, since these environments are (supposedly from what I read from the LaTeX Companion) lists...

Comment: @gniourf-gniourf: Yes it's possible to nested theorem environments. I try my example with amsart and I get the chaos. So I'm perplex, I don't know amsart.cls and I suppose  this class defines some theorem environments. I try my example with scrartcl.cls and it's fine

Comment: @gniourf-gniourf: In `amsart.cls`you can find this : `\renewcommand{\newtheorem} ...`. The class modifies `newtheorem` and perhaps` there is a little conflict between the class and `hyperref`. It's only a warning but it would  be good to know why !

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of search, I finally found a simple solution: load `hyperref` before any ams package. Replacing the `amsart` document class by `article` class and pulling the `hyperref` package above the `amsthm` one solved my problem.

It does not always work, though. It can reduce the number of such warnings, and in some cases make them disappear.

For those who do want to use the `amsart` class that is still not a solution, though...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (seemingly) and found that the cause was not having loaded the `siunitx` package.  I don't know why it had that effect, but it did.