# pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (nam e{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I get the following warning

> ```
> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1})
> has been already used, duplicate ignored
> ```

when compiling the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{[Title]}
\author{N.N.}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{[Section]}

\end{document}
```

I have tried find ways to get rid of this warning by searching in other places and I have read [PDFTeX destination … ignored](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyperdupdest) and the other question in this place [pdfTeX warning: destination with same identifier has been already used, duplicate ignored (weird behavior)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/pdftex-warning-destination-with-same-identifier-has-been-already-used-duplicate).

Comment: See [this FAQ answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=pdfpagelabels)

Comment: I've tried what that FAQ describes without success.

Comment: Sure, the FAQ explains that when there is a separate unnumbered title page (as you have here) then the technique will not help.

Comment: Just came upon this thread. My problem is that the style file I'm required to use kills \thepage with the line `\let\thepage\relax`. I've tried the recommendation in the FAQ entry to no avail.

Comment: @Suresh If the answer below does not work for you you should comment the answer and not this question.

Comment: @N.N. I answered here because both the FAQ soln here AND the answer below don't work. so I wasn't sure where to comment.

Comment: @Suresh: Use `\pagenumbering{none}` in your document to fix your problem that was caused by `\let\thepage\relax` in the style file (for example, in ACM's sig-alternate.cls).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

One way to avoid the problem is to change the (invisible) numbering style of the title page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\title{[Title]}
\author{N.N.}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{[Section]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another way to solve it is to disable the pageanchors for the titlepage with `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` and reactivate them later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I see the difference in the PDF file between the two solutions (the one answered and yours), but which one would be a best practice?

Answer (score 50):

As requested by the comments: Another way to solve it is to disable the pageanchors for the titlepage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\title{[Title]}
\author{N.N.}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents

\section{[Section]}
\end{document}
```

It is a matter of taste which solution is better. hyperref needs page anchors with unique names e.g. to add links to the index. Changing the page numbering style as Enrico did in his answer is a logical and adequate method to do it. On the other side: If there is a part of the document where one don't need pageanchors, disabling them is also adequate.

Comment: This solution worked really well for me. Thank you very much @Ulrike-Fischer.

Answer (score 9):

I am required to use a template from my university, hence, there is no freedom to move parts of the document into different places. My understanding is that many packages conflict with hyperref (See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyperdupdest), the only thing that worked for me was to load the float package before hyperref.

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, in the documentation of `hyperref` you can read, that `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded, because it redifines a lot of commands. There are only a few exception from that mentioned in the documentation (for ecampe `cleverf`) ...

Answer (score 1):

I had this warning because I put `\tableofcontents` before `abstract` at the beginning of my document. It disappeared when I swapped them. This reversed order also makes more sense I guess.

I see it is not the case in your case but maybe it will help someone else like it would have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the warnings were caused by cases where I used display-style equations using `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, including a `\nonumber` command.  Replacing this with `\[` and `\]` and removing the `\nonumber` removed the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Very very late, but just in case that it helps someone else:
I had a title page in an article and didn't want it to be counted as page 1 and had therefore used `\setcounter{page}{1}` after the title page, which caused the warning which is described in the title of this question.

I solved this problem by using instead `\setcounter{page}{0}` *inside* the title page. The number 0 didn't show up since it was a title page, the following, first page of the article got the correct number 1 and the warning disappeared.

Seems like LateX doesn't like unnumbered pages...