# pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier

Tags: errors

I have little experience with latex but am using it to write my undergraduate project, recently the error messages have come up and it wont allow me to build my pdf and comes up with the following error messages.

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ci' on page j undefined on input line k.
```

I am using an embedded bibliography `\begin{thebibliography}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see the related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18924/pdftex-warning-ext4-destination-with-the-same-identifier-nam-epage-1-has?

Comment: Yeh thanks @egreg I have looked at  that and have managed to fix the page numbering problem but still nearly all of my references are undefined.

Comment: Without a minimal example it's difficult to say. If you have a line `\bibitem{ci}` in the bibliography, then `\cite{ci}` will work.