# How to get rid of a particular PDFLaTeX warning?

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I am writing my bachelor's thesis and I want for the first pages (title, table of contents, abstract) to be numbered with roman numbers, and the rest of the pages with arabic numbers. I have almost managed to do this, except the fact that my abstract page and table of contents page are numbered with the same number, i, and I get the following warning:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{page.i}) has been already used,    
duplicate ignored <to be read again>\relaxl.31 \newpage[1
```

I have read this page [Hyperref and repeated page numbers](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-pdfpagelabels) and I have tried all these 3 options in the file `mystyle.sty`:

```
\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage[plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
```

But none of these help.
Here is my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[c]{Header}
\fancyfoot[c]{Town, year}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{35.0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\newpage
\input{abstract.tex}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\input{./tex/chapter1.tex}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\input{./tex/chapter2.tex}
\input{./tex/chapter3.tex}
\input{./tex/chapter4.tex}
\input{./tex/chapter5.tex}
\input{./tex/chapter6.tex}

\end{document}
```

This is my `abstract.tex` file:

```
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
```

And here is an example for one of the chapters file:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{into}
Introduction
```

The `mystyle.sty` file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

Comment: This looks like missing a `\phantomsection` statement.

Comment: There is some wrong anchor for bookmarks etc. inside from the `\maketitle` command. Omit it and try to make the title by hand. The message should vanish!

Comment: How can I make the title by hand? If I comment the `\maketitle` command I still get the warning

Comment: Why do the tableofcontents and the abstract have the same number? Do you reset it? Why? To avoid the warning see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18927/2388 (including the comments)

Comment: Many details are missing. How do you write your abstract? Please, make a self contained example.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I dont' know why the page number is repeated because after every page I put a `\newpage` command. I have read the page you told me about and if I write the `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` command the warning disappears, but still nothing changes in the numbering; @egreg I have edited the question

Comment: That's not a self contained example: We don't have your mystyle.sty. Beside this: abstract uses internally the titlepage option which resets the page number -- another reason to use a better class like scrrprt or memoir. You can also try the `notitlepage` option.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the `mystyle.sty` file. Using the `notitlepage` option is not a good choice because although the page numbering is good, I have no header or footer on the title page. Would it be better if I didn't have separate files?