# Division by zero error when using adjustbox and makebox

Tags: includegraphics, tikz-pic, adjustbox

first question in this stack community. I'm trying to create a new style for title page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, top=4cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.0cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,89,0}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor= green,
    linkcolor = black,
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\url{mycompany.com}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{Logo.jpg}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}

  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{3cm}

    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{3.5pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}

    {\Huge Sample Report\\}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}

    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.5pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    {\LARGE  Italy \\}
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}

    {\large  23 May 2019 \\}

  \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
\fancyhead[R]{Sample Report}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}} % start page counting

\lipsum[1-8]
\lipsum[1-8]


\end{document}
```

The pdf file renders fine but I get an error in my IDE (pasted below) corresponding to the `\end{adjustbox}` - not sure how I can fix this?

> ! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.See the graphics package
>   documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help....
>   \end{adjustbox}

Here's what I want the page to look like (blanked out areas - title, name, header etc. had confidential identifying information so had to be removed):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @Gautam `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}` is useless given the `\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{...}` and the contents of the `tikzpicture` environment is not valid Ti*k*Z syntax. If you replace the whole `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}`, the compilation works (but then, the `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth} ... \end{adjustbox}` seems to be a convoluted way to do something that could probably be done with simply `\includegraphics`). Also, please use `example-image` instead of `Logo.jpg`: it's always available.

Comment: @Gautam Maybe what you want is `\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}\par` at the beginning of the `center` environment.

Comment: @frougon thanks! It works - I don't get any errors anymore. However, the image that I was using on my title page doesn't span the entire page anymore (it did previously). I tried using `\begin{tikzpicture}` with `\paperwidth` but that didn't work either - I have a small amount of empty space left on the left margin now.

Comment: @frougon using `\makebox` in the `\begin{center}` loop places the image in the body of the document whereas I want it in the header only.

Comment: In the header? What does it mean?

Comment: @frougon I added an image of the page as I would like it to appear. The green logo on the top is in the 'header' area of the document and I need to span the entire page width.

Comment: More to the point, tikzpicture does not print any text which shows up inside.  This is mostly to ignore spaces, but it ignores everything, including the \makebox.  So you are effectively trying to expand \hbox{} to fill the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{Logo.jpg}}
```

that you put inside the `tikzpicture` doesn't conform to any Ti*k*Z syntax (it would be valid inside a `node` command, but the `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}` is useless anyway, since you are already passing `width=\textwidth` to `\includegraphics`). Thus, Ti*k*Z doesn't recognize it and, being a *very forgiving parser,* simply ignores it. As a consequence, the resulting `tikzpicture` has zero width. Then you put this `tikzpicture` inside `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\paperwidth} ... \end{adjustbox}`. This is what triggers the division by 0, when `adjustbox` divides `\paperwidth` by the width of the `tikzpicture` (`0pt`) in order to compute the scale factor.

The following code will produce the desired layout:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0, anchor=north] at (current page.north)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

for instance after your `\thispagestyle{fancy}` (but you may want to put `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the first page instead, if this is the only thing you wanted in the header there). The scaling preserves the aspect ratio of the image. Here is a full, self-contained example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0, anchor=north] at (current page.north)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Because of the `remember picture` option, you need to compile the document twice.

[image]

## Other errors in your code

Concerning the other error message that is printed with your code, namely:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

it is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18924/pdftex-warning-ext4-destination-with-the-same-identifier-nam-epage-1-has). In short, you can solve it by putting for instance `\pagenumbering{Alph}` before `\begin{titlepage}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\end{titlepage}`.

Also, this kind of thing is incorrect:

```latex
{\Huge Sample Report\\}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
```

You can use either:

```latex
{\Huge Sample Report\par}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
```

or

```latex
{\Huge Sample Report\\[2\baselineskip]
other text in Huge size}
```

(the latter *only if there is text immediately following,* as in this example).

Comment: Thanks! This works too - I seem to lose the horizontal `\headrule` but I'm guessing that's been covered by the image file - I am okay with that. I do want some text in the page (need to stick with the official template) namely the document title, author name and date. Is there a way to add a 'footer' as well? perhaps by using another `tikzpicture` but anchored `south` at `current page.south`?

Comment: Yes, or `\fancyfoot`, depending on the positioning requirements. With the `current page` Ti*k*Z node, you can easily place stuff flush against the page edges. Headers and footers (`fancyhdr`) are not that close to the edges, unless you define layout parameters very specially. They are more suited for run-in headings and page numbers. I've explained how to fix another error in your code, please look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Gautam I explained why you got the division by zero, proposed a solution that apparently achieves the layout you wanted and fixed several other unrelated errors in your code. Is there any reason why you didn't upvote nor accept my answer? Please consult “[How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)” in case you don't know what this means, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying it out until now - it works.