# Bracket in front of warning destination with the same identifier

Tags: bugs

The following code prodcues the warning "pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored".
How to resolve this warning has been described in the answers to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18924/120953).

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    abc
\end{document}
```

This warning is not reported by [latexrun](https://github.com/aclements/latexrun) or [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/).
I am wondering whether it is not recognized because of the bracket which is printed in front of the warning.
On stdout it looks like this:

```
]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
```

In the log file the bracket is not present.
Is it intended that the output on stdout and in the log file are different?
Does the bracket have a meaning?

This happens when running pdflatex, xelatex does not give a warning.
Why does xelatex not report a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bracket is also in the log, it is the closing bracket from the page output starting with `[1`:

```
 [1

{c:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]pdfTeX warning (
ext4):
```

The warning is a low-level engine warning. If you want that `texstudio` or some other tool reports it, make a feature request.

`xelatex` can't detect duplicate destinations. But if you would compile with

```
 xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" file
```

`xdvipdfmx` would report

```
 xdvipdfmx:warning: Object @page.1 already defined.
```

Comment: interesting, in my log file the bracket is at the end of the line two lines above, not at the beginning of the line of the warning. Is there a documentation on this page output and how the output of low level warnings looks like? Is it common that low level warnings are not on a separate line?