# Label page numbers differently for the viewer

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering

I'm writing two documents (using a specific template), each of 5 pages, in one `.tex` file.
Between them, I added

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

to reset the page numbering. The numbers displayed in the resulting PDF are fine: 1-5 and 1-5.

However, the PDF viewer (e.g. SumatraPDF) isn't happy with that. Instead of numbering the pages from 1-10 (e.g. for seeking a page), it has: 1-5, 1.1-5.1.

How can I keep the page numbering that I want but tell the PDF something else?
It might have something to do with the PDF catalog.

Comment: Related: [pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18924/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal example provides a way around having duplicate page numbers. The key is to add a differing TeX/PDF `\thepage`, together with the `pdfpagelabels=false` setting for [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\sloppy

% First set of 5 pages
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-25]

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}% Reset page counter
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\arabic{page}}{X\arabic{page}}}%

% Second set of 5 pages
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[26-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Under the assumption that you may have different section numbers within each component of the document, you could even do the following in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\arabic{page}}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}}
```