# strange error in \end{document}

Tags: errors, templates, acm

I am using ACM template to write a paper for a conference.
This is my main document structure:

```
.....
......
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}
\input{introduction}

\section{Related Work}
\label{sec:rWork}
\input{relatedWork}
...
\section{Concluding Remarks}
\label{sec:conclusion}
\input{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sigproc}
%\balancecolumns

\end{document}
```

Somehow every time I create pdf (PDF Textify) using WinEdt. I get strange error as shown in the following image.

[image: error screenshot]

<sup>source: https://plus.google.com/photos/111071276548636760112/albums/5913461747487936689</sup>

> ```
> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has
> been already used, duplicate ignored
> <to be read again>
>                   \relax
> l. 177 \end{document}
>                      [2
> ```

This is what my .bib entries are

```
@article{bisbal1999legacy,
  title={Legacy information systems: Issues and directions},
  author={Bisbal, Jes{\'u}s and Lawless, Deirdre and Wu, Bing and Grimson, Jane},
  journal={IEEE Soft.},
  volume={16},
  number={5},
  pages={103--111},
  year={1999},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{veerman2004revitalizing,
  title={Revitalizing modifiability of legacy assets},
  author={Veerman, Niels},
  journal={J. Softw. Maint. Evol.: Res. Prac.},
  volume={16},
  number={4-5},
  pages={219--254},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{arranga1997cobol,
  title={Cobol: Perception and reality},
  author={Arranga, Edmund C and Coyle, Frank P},
  journal={IEEE Comp.},
  volume={30},
  number={3},
  pages={126--128},
  year={1997},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@MISC{Toby2008burden,
  author =       {Sucharov, Toby and Rice, Philip},
  title =        {The Burden of Legacy},
  howpublished = {Online},
  year =         {2008},
  source =       {http://www.ncc.co.uk/article/?articleid=15665}
}

@book{glaser2009discovery,
  title={The discovery of grounded theory: Strategies for qualitative research},
  author={Glaser, Barney G and Strauss, Anselm L},
  year={1967},
  publisher={Aldine Transaction},
  ADDRESS = {Chicago, Illionios}
}

@article{adolph2011using,
  title={Using grounded theory to study the experience of software development},
  author={Adolph, Steve and Hall, Wendy and Kruchten, Philippe},
  journal={Emp. Soft. Eng.},
  volume={16},
  number={4},
  pages={487--513},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As to the error message, check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18924) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13083)

Comment: It is not an error, but just a `hyperref` warning. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124520/27635. You're using a very very old WinEdt version, and probably it is reported as an error. I suggest you to upgrade to the latest version (8.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have several pages with `\renewcommand*{\thepage}{}`. Package `hyperref` adds page anchors at each page. They are used by index commands, thus `\thepage` is used for naming the anchors.

If you do not have an index, then you can add the following `hyperref` option:

```
pageanchor=false
```

Otherwise, page anchors can be disabled for some pages only, e.g.:

```
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{}
...

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
```