# Understanding Warning 'Destination with the same identifier has been already used' caused by Theorems

Tags: hyperref, theorems, warnings

In the following mwe I get two warnings: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'foo' on page 2 undefined on input line 29.` and `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{definition.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`.

While the first is obvious I don't see where the second would come from. The second warning disappears if, e.g. the `\newpage` is removed or the wrong citation is removed or corrected or `cleveref` is removed. It also disappears if I use `\newtheorem` instead of `thmtools` and `\declaretheorem`.

Can somebody explain me why that warning occurs? I started out with a big document which contained all these things, hence my desire to know.

I researched similar questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18924/34908), [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyperdupdest), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13083/34908) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13083/34908) but it seems to be something different. Also I respect the order of loading packages.

### The MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,parent=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,qed=$\triangle$,sibling=theorem]{definition}

% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
% \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap}

\section{Sec1}

\begin{definition}
Text
\end{definition}

\newpage

\section{Sec2}

The reference \cite{foo} is undefined.
\begin{definition}
Text
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The two `\declaretheorem` directives should occur *after* `hyperref` and `cleveref` are loaded. Make this change irrespective of any `\newpage` directives in the body of the document.

Comment: Arg.. thanks! :-) Could you post this as answer, then I can accept.

Comment: @Mico Do you know if it is documented that theorems should be declared after loading all packages? Asking cause I could not find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Re-posting an earlier comment, so that the query can be treated as having received an answer.)

The immediate cause of the problem is the fact that the two `\declaretheorem` directives are currently placed before rather than after the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages are loaded.

Do change the placement of the two directives, irrespective of any `\newpage` directives that may be present in the body of the document.

To answer your follow-up question: The user guide of the `cleveref` package does mention that while all theorem-related packages -- such as `amsthm` and `thmtools` -- should be loaded before `cleveref`, statements of the `\newtheorem` and `\declaretheorem` variety should occur only *after* `cleveref` is loaded. (For more detail, see the final sentence in the second bullet point in section 14.1 on page 25 of the package's user guide.)